# Delete row if check box is switched to false

Tags: excel, vba

I hope your weeks are going well.

Currently writing a data entry from in a VBA user form,

It will be using an array of checkboxes to select size which then fills a row with the other data provided when that checkbox is ticked.

I'm currently running into an issue where I don't know what code to run to have the function delete its previous data when the checkbox is unticked.

```
Private Sub CheckBox0k_Click()
    '''Input        
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, RowInsert As Long
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("stock")
    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
        
        RowInsert = .Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Find("*", .Cells(LastRow, "A"), xlValues, , , xlPrevious).row
        RowInsert = RowInsert + 1

        'add the uk size input code here
    
        '''Checkbox based search
        ''Start

        If Me.CheckBox0k.Value = True Then
            ''''This has to match the number of rows input below    
            .Cells(RowInsert, "A").Resize(1, 8).Value = Array( _
                Me.txtDate.Text, _
                Me.textboxparentsku.Text, _
                Me.textboxsku.Text, _
                Me.comboboxbrand.Text, _
                Me.comboboxclosure.Text, _
                Me.comboboxgender.Text, _
                Me.comboboxmaterial.Text, _
                Me.comboboxmodel.Text _
            )
            ws.Range("I" & RowInsert).Value = CheckBox0k.Caption   
        



'This is the code I'm having issues with
ElseIf CheckBox0k.Value = False Then   
            .Cells(RowInsert, "A").Resize(1, 8).Value = ws.Range("I" & RowInsert).Value = ""
        End If

        ''Finish
        Set ws = Nothing    
    End With 
End Sub
```

[A picture of the current UI with the multiple checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRzZT.png)

Comment: Please read [ask] there is no question in your post. Also describe where you got errors or where exactly you got stuck.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply  I have edited the post and code

Comment: Please, try `.Cells(RowInsert, "A").Resize(1, 8).Value = ""`...

Comment: Do you want to delete the row or just clear its content? `.Cells(RowInsert, "A").Resize(1, 8).Value = ws.Range("I" & RowInsert).Value = ""` is just weird (see there's 2 `=`?)

Comment: Thanks for both responses, Clearing content from the table in excel is a better descriptor for what I want to do. I'm quite new to VBA and as such a lot of the way I've put things together is very hacky and not clean apologies.

Comment: @Sirico Please try FaneDuru's suggestion. If it still don't work then it helps to step through the code line by line to identify what went wrong.

Comment: Thank you I have it currently doesn't affect my table but it also isn't throwing up any errors so I will try and see how I can apply it. Thank you both

Comment: It looks that it cannot work (exactly) in the way I suggested... In order to help, I would need to know more about the process. I men, do you need clearing the last 8 entries (columns)? If so, the working solution should be something like `.Cells(RowInsert, "A").Resize(1, - 9).Value = ""`. But your code must check if there are data in the first columns of the row to be processed and warn...

Comment: Would it help if I posted the full code? You are correct I need an unticking of the checkbox in the UI to undo the data input true statement in the previous code which is currently 9 columns.

Comment: @FaneDuru can you set your comment as an awnser so I can accept that, weird accepting my own comment when you put me on the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to help, we would need to know more about the process. I men, do you need clearing the last 8 entries (columns)? If so, the working solution should be something like

```
.Cells(RowInsert, "A").Resize(1, - 9).Value = ""
```

But your code must check if there are data in the first columns of the row to be processed and warn...

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have sorted it I made a new rule called `RowInvert = RowInsert - 1` and put that into FaneDuru's code:

```
ElseIf Me.CheckBox0k.Value = False Then .Cells(RowInvert, "A").Resize(1, 9).Value = ""
```